# Como insertar una nueva lista a una matriz ya generada?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El problema me dice que dada una matriz que este cargada con **-Electrodoméstico-**, **-Marca-**, **-Precio-** y **-Stock**, le pregunte al usuario si quiere agregar un nuevo Electrodoméstico.
Ya dimensione la matriz (4x4) y le cargue los elementos.
Ahora lo que no se es como puedo añadirle otro vector a la matriz, tengo la idea pero no se como pasarla código
Acá les dejo algo del código

```
def carga_matriz(f, c, vector):
for i in range(f):
    vector.append([0]*c)
    for j in range (c):
        vector[i][j]=int(input("Ingrese los elementos:"))


def añadir_producto(nuevo_vector, filas, columnas, vector):
electro=int(input("Ingrese el nuevo electrodomestico: "))
for elec in vector:
    if elec.find(electro) != -1:
        print("El electrodomestico ya existe")
    else:
        for i in range(columna):
            nuevo_vector[i]=int(input("Ingrese los nuevos elementos"))##el nuevo vector para cargarlo a la matriz

"""
Parametros globales
"""
filas = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de filas: "))
columnas = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas: "))
vector = []
carga_matriz(filas, columnas, vector)

print("Desea Agrandar la matriz?")
nueva_fila=input()
if nueva_fila== "si":  
##crear nueva fila
    nuevo_vector=[None]*columnas
    añadir_producto(nuevo_vector, filas, columnas, vector)
```

> Lo podria hacer con un .insert()?

Comment: Por favor, si la respuesta te fue útil, acéptala presionando el checklist (✅) que se encuentra a la izquierda de ella. De esa manera muestras tu agradecimiento con quien te ayudó y marcas tu pregunta como respondida para que no quede abierta eternamente. Actualmente tienes 5 preguntas casi todas con respuestas muy buenas y no has aceptado ninguna.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer con `append()`, pero tendrías que pasar una lista

Ejemplo genérico:

Tenemos una matriz de 4x4

```
m = [[1,2,3, 4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[12,14,15,16]]
```

Y tenemos una lista de 4 elementos

```
v = [17,18,19,20]
```

Agregamos los elementos de `v` en `m`

```
m.append(v)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
m = [[1,2,3, 4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[12,14,15,16]]
print('Antes: ', m)
v = [17,18,19,20]
m.append(v)
print('Después: ', m)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Antes:  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [12, 14, 15, 16]]
Después:  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [12, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]
```